# Load a UIImage from the local directory

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to load a UIImage from the documents directory as per below:

```
    var documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    documentsPath.append("/filescheme/filescheme/images/3.png")
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath)
    do {
        let imageData = try Data.init(contentsOf: url)
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

and failed to create data from the directory, 
the error: "The file “3.png” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

[image: Screenshot of URL path]

Comment: try this line: let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: documentsPath)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32799162/6080920

Comment: i tried this , image was nil

Answer (score 2):

You can use the loadImage function and pass the image path, it check if the imageFile exists at the path and the returns the UIImage from the given path using contentsOfFile method of String

```
func loadImage(at path: String) -> UIImage? {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentPath = paths[0]
    let imagePath = documentPath.appending(path)
    guard fileExists(at: imagePath) else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath) else {
        return nil
    }
    return image
}

func fileExists(at path: String) -> Bool {
    return FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path)
}
```

Use:

```
loadImage(at: "/filescheme/filescheme/images/3.png")
```

Comment: The second `guard let` is redundant. Just `return UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)`. It returns either the image or `nil`

Comment: Why FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) returns false, while image file exists at this path ?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NIpq.png

Comment: not sure why its returning false, can you verify the image path is proper

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
documentsPath.append("/filescheme/filescheme/images/3.png")
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: documentsPath)
```

You can directly use documentsPath without convert it to data

Answer (score 0):

i have found the problem , the folder was named "fileScheme" not "filescheme" so,

```
var documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
documentsPath.append("/filescheme/fileScheme/images/3.png")
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: documentsPath) // it works
```